# Making Statusbar Translucent for an app in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-apps

Im a newbie for android apps development.
Im developing an app, in which i need a status bar translucent as Google Now launcher's app has. How to get the clean transparent status bar so that my section image can be viewed in statusbar too...

Comment: Sorry its not about appbar its about statusbar. thanks for cdslijngard for answering. Now, It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your Styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

After that, apply the style to your view by adding it to the activity in your AndroidManifest file.